# Sorting documents in N1QL using array field of the document

Tags: sorting, couchbase, sql++

We need to sort documents using array field in the document using N1QL

We have following documents , **PCI**:

```
{
  "id": "pci1",
  "_class" = "PCI",
  "productDSL": {
    "parameters": {
      "tpnb": ["02","04"]
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": "pci2",
  "_class" = "PCI",
  "productDSL": {
    "parameters": {
      "tpnb": ["01","02","04"]
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": "pci3",
  "_class" = "PCI",
  "productDSL": {
    "parameters": {
      "tpnb": ["01","02"]
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": "pci4",
  "_class" = "PCI",
  "productDSL": {
    "parameters": {
      "tpnb": ["02","03"]
    }
  }
}
```

We need to "order by" according to the tpnb field which is an array.
So the result should return in the following order

```
pci3,pci2,pci4,pci1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following query. ORDER is based on the array as whole

```
SELECT id FROM default
WHERE _class = "PCI"
ORDER BY productDSL.parameters.tpnb;
```